# Domain Change and Old Sitemap in Search Console

Tags: seo, google-search-console, xml-sitemap

We recently changed our domain from www.OldDomain.com to www.NewDomain.com.
All four properties have been setup in Google Search Console for the new domain, and the sitemap has been added to the preferred domain.

I noticed in Search Console that we still have the old domain property, and that property still has a sitemap in Search Console.

When I type in the URL for the old domain's sitemap (www.OldDomain.com/sitemap.xml) it automatically redirects to the new domain's sitemap URL (www.NewDomain.com/sitemap_index.xml). This sitemap was created by the Yoast plugin.

I do not see a reason to keep the old sitemap, but wanted to get some opinions before I remove it.

Any experience/thoughts on this issue?

Comment: When you say "remove it", you mean just remove it from Search Console, as opposed to making that URL 404 Not found on your site, right?

Comment: That is correct.....remove the sitemap from Search Console.

Comment: If it is a result of a redirect, you don't need to remove it. Just ignore it. Both sites will be in flux for a while.

Comment: It will most likely report an error or that no URLs are indexed. Nothing to worry about. You can remove it from GSC if you want.